# Making a url regex global

Tags: php, regex, url

I've been searching for a regex to replace plain text url's in a string (the string can contain more than 1 url), by:

```
 <a href="url">url</a>
```

and I found this:
http://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex

I would like to use the diegoperini's regex (which according to the tests is the best):

```
_^(?:(?:https?|ftp)://)(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?!10(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!127(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!169\.254(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!192\.168(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+-?)*[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+-?)*[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}]{2,})))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:/[^\s]*)?$_iuS
```

But I want o make it global to replace all the url's in a string.
When I use this:

```
/_(?:(?:https?|ftp)://)(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?!10(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!127(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!169\.254(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!192\.168(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+-?)*[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+-?)*[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}]{2,})))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:/[^\s]*)?_iuS/g
```

It does not work, how do I make this regex global and what does the underscore at the beginning and the "_iuS", at the end, means?

I would like to use it with php so I am using:

```
preg_replace($regex, '<a href="$0">$0</a>', $examplestring);
```

Comment: Sorry did not understand, that last comment, what's define?

Comment: `preg_replace` replaces all occurrences by default, you should be able to just remove the `^` and `$` anchors.

Comment: Yes you are right, I was using an url like this: www.google.pt , as the second url in the text string, and I thought it was not being replaced because it was only replacing the first match but turns out the regex doesn't match urls like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The underscores are the regex delimiters, the i, u and S are pattern modifiers :

> i (PCRE_CASELESS)
>
> ```
> If this modifier is set, letters in the pattern match both upper and lower 
> case letters.
> ```
>
> U (PCRE_UNGREEDY)
>
> ```
> This modifier inverts the "greediness" of the quantifiers so that they are 
> not greedy by default, but become greedy if followed by ?. It is not compatible
> with Perl. It can also be set by a (?U) modifier setting within the pattern 
> or by a question mark behind a quantifier (e.g. .*?).
> ```
>
> S
>
> ```
> When a pattern is going to be used several times, it is worth spending more 
> time analyzing it in order to speed up the time taken for matching. If this 
> modifier is set, then this extra analysis is performed. At present, studying 
> a pattern is useful only for non-anchored patterns that do not have a single 
> fixed starting character.
> ```

For more informations see http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

When you added the / ... /g , you added another regex delimiter plus the modifier g wich does not exists in PCRE, that's why it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @verdesmarald and used this pattern in the following function:

```
$string = preg_replace_callback(
        "_(?:(?:https?|ftp)://)(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?!10(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!127(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!169\.254(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!192\.168(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+-?)*[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+-?)*[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}]{2,})))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:/[^\s]*)?_iuS",
        create_function('$match','
            $m = trim(strtolower($match[0]));
            $m = str_replace("http://", "", $m);
            $m = str_replace("https://", "", $m);
            $m = str_replace("ftp://", "", $m);
            $m = str_replace("www.", "", $m);

            if (strlen($m) > 25)
            {
                $m = substr($m, 0, 25) . "...";
            }

            return "<a href=\"$match[0]\">$m</a>";
                '), $string);

    return $string;
```

It seem to do the trick, and resolve an issue I was having. As @verdesmarald said, removing the ^ and $ characters allowed the pattern to work even in my pre_replace_callback().

Only thing that concerns me, is how efficient is the pattern. If used in a busy/high traffic web app, could it cause a bottle neck?

**UPDATE**

The above regex pattern breaks if there is a trail dot at the end of the path section of a url, like so `http://www.mydomain.com/page.`. To solve this I modified the final part of the regex pattern by adding `^.` making the final part look like so `[^\s^.]`. As I read it, do not match a trailing space or dot.

In my tests so far it seems to be working fine.

Comment: Please post this as self answer to your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14410134/preg-replace-callback-pattern-issue rather than this question.

Comment: @nhahtdh Not now I won't, as I've found with further testing this pattern also breaks when faced with a url and bold closing tag like so: `http://mydomain/contact</b>` and if you take the backticks out you'll notice that stackoverflow also has the same fault, like so: http://mydomain/contact</b>